# Javascript using Parameter from URL

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, area

i have a Problem my Area Shape href="/kosmetikstudios/deutschland/**Bayern**" tag look so. And i will to use the Parameter "Bayern" (this is the last parameter of the url).

I need this dynamic.

Here are my Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var mName="passiv";
    $("#map area").mouseenter(function(){

      mName = $(this).attr("href"); // i don't have idea to implement this
      bName="images/" +mName + ".png";
      $("#map img").attr("src",bName);

    });

    $("#map area").mouseleave(function(){
      bName="images/Europa.png";
      $("#map img").attr("src",bName);

    });

  });
</script>
```

Here are my HTML Code

```
 <area shape="poly" coords="356,300,355,299,354,298....." href="/kosmetikstudios/deutschland/Bayern" title="Kosmetikstudios in Bayern" alt="Kosmetikstudios in Bayern" />

<area shape="poly" coords="156,200,425,699,154,298....." href="/kosmetikstudios/deutschland/Berlin" title="Kosmetikstudios in Berlin" alt="Kosmetikstudios in Bayern" />
```

I hope anybody can help me.

Regards,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mName = this.href.substring(
    this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1
);
```

Comment: You can simply use `this.href`, the jQuery objects are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extracting the value out of the URL you could set a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to store the name.

For example:

HTML

```
<area shape="poly" data-name="Bayern" href="/kosmetikstudios/deutschland/Bayern" />
<area shape="poly" data-name="Berlin" href="/kosmetikstudios/deutschland/Berlin" />
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var mName="passiv";
    $("#map area").mouseenter(function(){

      //read the data attributes
      mName = $(this).data("name");

      bName="images/" +mName + ".png";
      $("#map img").attr("src", bName);

    });

    $("#map area").mouseleave(function(){
      bName="images/Europa.png";
      $("#map img").attr("src",bName);

    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Cool. Be awesome if you could upvote or accept it as answer if it helped. thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
mName = $(this).attr("href").split("/").reverse()[0];
```

Comment: Consider `this.href.split("/").reverse()[0];`

Comment: Yes ofc, native JS is better.